# can we access static member variable of pure virtual class?

Tags: c++, static, virtual

Please consider the following code:

```
#include<iostream>

/* pure virtual class*/
class cTest {
    public:
        cTest(void);
        static void sFuncG(void);
        static void sFuncS(int);
        virtual void vFunc(void) = 0;
    private:
        static int  sVar;
};
/*the constructor dose nothing meaningful*/
cTest::cTest(void)
{
    return;
}

/*there are two static function who needs to access the static member variable*/
void cTest::sFuncS(int num)
{
    sVar = num;
}

void cTest::sFuncG(void)
{
    std::cout<<sVar<<std::endl;
}
/*the derived class*/
class cDrvd : public cTest {
    public:
        cDrvd(int);
        virtual void vFunc(void);
    private:
        int mem;
};

cDrvd::cDrvd(int num)
{
    mem = num;
}

void cDrvd::vFunc(void)
{
    cTest::sFuncS(mem);
}

int main()
{
    cDrvd myClass(5);
    cTest::sFuncG();
    return 0;

}
```

When I try to build the code, I am getting linker error:

```
me@My-PC:MyTestProgs$ g++ -o testStatic testStatic.cpp 
/tmp/ccgUzIGI.o: In function `cTest::sFuncS(int)':
testStatic.cpp:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `cTest::sVar'
/tmp/ccgUzIGI.o: In function `cTest::sFuncG()':
testStatic.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `cTest::sVar'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I found the problem in a large code and tried to reproduce it in the above code of mine.

**What I understood is:**

- static member variables are created when the 1st instance of the class is created.
- Here, no instance of class `cTest` is created, so the static member variable `sVar` is not present.
- As the class cTest is pure virtual, we can not create an instance of it. So we cannot access `sVar`.

***I am fairly new to c++*, keeping in that mind, Will anyone please confirm my understanding?**

**If that is the case, what is the workaround for the situation?**

Comment: It's because you haven't *defined* the static member variable `sVar`. If you have code referencing that variable, then it needs to be defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define static member

```
    static int  sVar;
```

independently of the class in implementation file.

```
int cTest::sVar = 0;  //initialization is optional if it's 0.
```

As far as your questions concerned :-

```
Q1) static member variables are created when the 1st instance of the class is created.
```

No static member is there even when no instance of class is created.

```
Q2) Here, no instance of class cTest is created, so the static member variable sVar 
is not present.
```

Static member variable would be there as explained above.

```
Q3)As the class cTest is pure virtual, we can not create an instance of it. 
So we cannot access sVar.
```

You can access `sVar` like `cTest::sVar`.

Comment: If sVar needs to be declared outside of the class, is it needed to be static?